# Netbeans 7.1 and windows 7 taskbar issue

Tags: netbeans, windows-7, taskbar, netbeans-7.1

I just did a clean install of windows 7 professional and netbeans seems to always duplicate itself on the taskbar next to the pinned icon.

I never had this issue until I formatted my machine.

Comment: belongs on http://superuser.com
Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users